# tapping space two time not replacing with full stop after if append some text in textView swift

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know why but if I write something in text view and after that if I tap space two-time then it will put a full stop afterward.but if I append some text in text view then if I tap space two-time it will add two space not replacing it with the full stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an iOS-Feature for easy writing. With that you don't have to write space dot every time, you can just tap double space at the end of a sentence.

So when you try that between two words, the system will not recognize that this is the end of a sentence and it will just use double space instead of full stop.

Comment: is there any way we can fix this?